# 404_error loads with another controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've been doing codeigneiter how many times, but this time, I can't trace where the error goes. This is just a basic problem but I found it hard to locate my error.

The problem is my controller loads with the 404_error. What is the reason why it loads the both.

Here is my code:

```
class Code extends CI_Controller {  
  public function __construct(){     
    parent::__construct();
  } 
   function index(){
      echo 'Welcome to this code';
   }
}//inside controllers/code.php



  class Page_error extends CI_Controller { 
      public function __construct(){
          echo 'error 404';
      }
   } // Here is controllers/page_error.php
```

In my routes.php

```
 $route['default_controller'] = "home";
 $route['404_override'] = 'page_error';
```

When I locate the url localhost/home it displays the homepage correctly as it is the default controller, but when I locate the url localhost/code, 
it displays the output below :

**Welcome to this codeerror 404**

Answer (score 0):

if you want to access each of these controllers separate make your routs as below.

$route['default_controller'] = 'code';
 $route['404_override'] = 'page_error';

localhost/code will get you the code class and localhost/404_override get you page_error

Answer (score 0):

Note that your Page_error is capitalized

try this

```
class Code extends CI_Controller{
    public function _construct(){
        parent::_construct();
    }

    public function index(){
        echo 'Welcome to this code';
    }

    public function Page_error(){
         echo 'error 404';
    }
}
```

**in your routes.php**

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = 'code/Page_error';
```